# Unexpected Token < after deploying Angular 2 app to Azure

Tags: javascript, angular, azure-web-app-service, angular-cli

I have a raw custom json file that i am using to give some functionality to the DOM elements. Everything is currently working locally in my angular 2 app, but when i publish to azure i run into issues with my javascript file and json

My first issue was that i couldnt find the url for the json file. Getting a 404. I was able to fix this by adding a custom web.config that i found on another question. I have the script directory located in the angular-cli.json so all of that is configured correctly as well.

When i try running the azure site i get "Unexpected token <" in one of the chunks. I had my custom js file referenced in the index before and it was the same error but on my custom js file, so im assuming this is where the issue lies. There is no "<" character in my custom js so What is happening here? Is there a proper way to go about debugging this issue?

Comment: probably because in your custom.js index.html is loaded & thats because of script written in web.config to solve the 404 issue.!

Comment: Look in your browser's *Network* console for the request for the JSON file. See what it is actually returning

Comment: nothing actually gets returned the error is thrown before.. hmm

Comment: can we get the link of azure deployed app ?

Comment: i ended up figuring it out, i was removing .json in the web config